# Ld Error during Go Installation on OSX

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-errors, go, clang

I try to build Go 1.2 from source but can't get it to work anymore. It worked yesterday but now ld always fails. I tried to reinstall Xcode command line tools. This is my Terminal output:

```
$ hg update go1.2
$ cd src
$ ./all.bash
# Building C bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist
ld: can't write output file: cmd/dist/dist for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am running OSX 10.9.1.

What could have happened that this error shows? (It worked yesterday, I just played around with homebrew)

What else can I do BESIDES reinstalling OSX?

Comment: Are the directories writable?

Comment: Yes they are, I install them inside my Users folder. (Same place where it worked yesterday)

Comment: they somehow weren't although they should have been and I have no idea what could have messed up the permissions overnight :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of [Volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266756/volker) I reapplied the correct permissions to the go folder. I didn't finde a specific folder that had the false permissions but resetting them for the whole go folder fixed it.

I did not think this would be an issue because I installed go in my home folder.